# calling methods from classes in the main method

Tags: java, class, methods

I am a bit stuck on this one. I am writing a java program with two classes, and then a test program to test the methods in the class. I am stuck on calling the two methods below in the main method. All of the class files (the test program class and the two other classes) are compiling and the IDE is not giving me any error messages, the calculation is just not occurring...

--Main Method Code:

```
//Call debit method
System.out.println("Please enter amount to be debited"); 
double amount=input.nextDouble(); 
account.debit(amount);   
System.out.printf("%.2f%n",balance); 

//Call credit method
System.out.println("Please enter amount to be credited"); 
amount=input.nextDouble(); 
account.credit(amount);   
System.out.printf("%.2f%n",balance);
```

--Account Class Code:

```
//Method for crediting account balance 
public void credit (double amount) {
  double newBalance=this.balance+amount;
  this.setBalance(newBalance);  
}

//Method for debiting account balance
public void debit (double amount) {
  if (amount<balance) {
  double newBalance=this.balance-amount;
  this.setBalance(newBalance); 
  } else {
  System.out.println("Insufficient Funds!"); 
}
```

NOTE: the balance setter is working, as it is called earlier in the test program...

Any help much appreciated!!!

Complete Code for Account Class:

```
public class Account {
private int accountId; 
private String accountName; 
private String accountAddress; 
private double balance; 
private Bank bank; 

//Default Constructor
public Account () {
}

//Getters
public int getAccountId () {
  return accountId; 
}

public String getAccountName () {
  return accountName; 
}

public String getAccountAddress () {
  return accountAddress; 
}

public double getBalance () {
  return balance; 
}

public Bank getBank () {
  return bank; 
}

//Setters
public void setAccountId (int accountId) {
  if (accountId <=10000000 || accountId >=99999999) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Account Id");
  } else {  
    this.accountId=accountId;
  }
}

public void setAccountName (String accountName) {
  if (accountName.length()>=10) {
    System.out.println("Too Long"); 
  } else {
    this.accountName=accountName;
  }
}

public void setAccountAddress (String accountAddress) { 
  this.accountAddress=accountAddress;
}

public void setBalance (double balance) {
  if (balance<0.0) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Balance");
  } else {  
    this.balance=balance; 
  }
}

public void setBank (Bank bank) {
  this.bank=bank; 
}

//Constructor to initialize accountId, accountName, accountAddress and Bank
public Account (int accountId, String accountName, String accountAddress, Bank bank) {
  this.setAccountId(accountId); 
  this.setAccountName(accountName); 
  this.setAccountAddress(accountAddress); 
  this.setBank(bank); 
}

//Method to print out account category based on balance
public void printAccountCategory () {
  if (balance<100.0) {
    System.out.println("Challenged Account"); 
  } else if (balance>=100.0 && balance<999.9) {
    System.out.println("Standard Account"); 
  } else if (balance>=1000.0 && balance<9999.9) {
    System.out.println("Promising Account"); 
  } else if (balance>=10000.0 && balance<99999.9) {
    System.out.println("Gold Star Account"); 
  } else {
    System.out.println("Super Duper Account"); 
  }
}

//Method to project balance based on compound interest and the number of years required
//Note: I took the formula using n (number of times the interest is compounded per year) as 1
public double projectNewBalance (int numberYears) {
  if (numberYears>0) {
    double interest=1;
    for (int i=1; i<=numberYears; i++) { 
      interest*=(1.0+bank.getInterestRate());  
    }
      double newBalance=balance*interest; 
      return newBalance;
    } else if (numberYears<0) {
      System.out.println("Invalid Value");
    } else {
      return balance;
    }
    return balance; 
  }

  //Method for crediting account balance
  public void credit (double amount) {
    double newBalance=this.balance+amount;
    this.setBalance(newBalance);  
  }

  //Method for debiting account balance
  public void debit (double amount) {
    if (amount<balance) {
      double newBalance=this.balance-amount;
      this.setBalance(newBalance); 
    } else {
      System.out.println("Insufficient Funds!"); 
    }
  }

  //toString method
  public String toString () {
    return "Account Id: "+accountId+", Account Name: " + accountName + ", Account Address: "+accountAddress+", Balance: "+balance+", Bank Details: "+bank.toString()+".";  
  }
}
```

Main Method Full Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankAccountTest {
  public static void main (String [ ] args) {
  //Create an instance of the Bank class
  Bank bank = new Bank ("WIT Bank", "Paddy Snow", 0.045);  

  //Create instance of Scanner class
  Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

  //Prompt user to input data to create an account
  System.out.println("Please enter an Account ID"); 
  int accountId=input.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Please enter an Account Name"); 
  String accountName=input.next(); 

  System.out.println("Please enter an Account Address"); 
  String accountAddress=input.next();

  //Create instance of the Account class
  Account account = new Account (accountId, accountName, accountAddress, bank); 

  //Print out details of account class
  System.out.println(account); 

  //Prompt user to enter balance for the account
  System.out.println("Please enter account balance"); 
  double balance=input.nextDouble(); 
  account.setBalance(balance); 

  //Use printAccountCategory method
  account.printAccountCategory(); 

  //Call projectNewBalance method
  // Note: Method tested with value of 10 years as mentioned in spec, 
  //    but user input also included I think it is more appropriate for the functionality of the program   
 //    int numberYears=10; 
 //    double newBalance1=account.projectNewBalance(numberYears); 
 //    System.out.println(""+newBalance1); 
   System.out.println("Please enter number of years"); 
   int numberYears=input.nextInt(); 
   double newBalance=account.projectNewBalance(numberYears); 
   System.out.printf("%.2f%n",newBalance);

    //Call debit method
    System.out.println("Please enter amount to be debited"); 
    double amount=input.nextDouble(); 
    account.debit(amount);   
    System.out.printf("%.2f%n",balance); 

    //Call credit method
    System.out.println("Please enter amount to be credited"); 
    amount=input.nextDouble(); 
    account.credit(amount);   
    System.out.printf("%.2f%n",balance);     
   }
}
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating the `Account` class in main?  When you print out `balance`, you should probably be updating its value from the `account` object first.  You should show the complete source code for your classes.

Comment: please show a complete example. Furthermore, are you programming OO or procedural? If second, then you have to declare everything as static. I suggest to start to c&p all in a single (class) file and run a quick test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers might always look the same because the local variable is not being updated before printing it out.

Make sure you update the value of `balance` before your call to `System.out.printf("%.2f%n",balance);`.

Something like:

`balance = account.getBalance();`

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be printing the balance of the object you have created and not just "balance":
System.out.println(account.getBalance())?